Type class in Scala with extension that overlaps in name with methods on type members
For a library I'm building in Scala 3 (current target 3.3), I am trying to construct a type class hierarchy to express various functionality I want to require from the types I'm using and introducing.
So my current code base has something like
trait HasDimension[A] {
  extension(a: A) def dim: Int
}
case class Simplex(vertices: Set)
given HasDimension[Simplex] with {
  extension(a: Simplex) def dim: Int = a.vertices.size - 1
}

During other times working on this library, I have implemented a member method called dim to do the exact work that HasDimension is trying to guarantee, and I would like to provide a given instance witnessing this. But when I write
given HasDimension[Cell] with {
  extension(a: Cell) override def dim: Int = a.dim
}

I get infinite loops and hung execution when the lookup for a.dim finds that I have an extension method on a and goes to look up the extension method.
If instead I write something like
given HasDimension[Cell] with {
  override def dim(a: Cell): Int = a.dim
}

I get an error message
error overriding method dim in trait HasDimension of type (t: Cell): Int;
  method dim of type (t: Cell): Int is a normal method, cannot override an extension method
  override def dim(t: Cell) = t.dim


I'm not fundamentally against changing my class hierarchies or picking a different approach to what I'm trying to do - but would need a few pointers to how. Except for where I get this syntax collision, type classes seem like the technique I need.
Down the line, I end up combining these type classes, so that a later definition that I use is
def HasBoundary[T] {
  extension(t:T) def boundary: Chain[T]
}
def Cell[T] extends HasDimension[T] with HasBoundary[T]

And eventually I want to get to a point in the hierarchy where a user can specify the data types they want to work with (by instantiating a context object of some sort) and all the (topological) methods and functionality they want is instantiated for their choice of data types.

"But when I write ... I get infinite loops and hung execution..." Can't reproduce https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/0vax0uL4S2WxIiEJMAdPbw/1 Please publish complete code of MCVE.
